# Website loads slowly

Tags: apache, zen-cart

When I make a search or just simply browse on my site it is really slow. I am using Zen Cart for my new Web Shopping.

My site is: http://shopfarmacia.it

Comment: Please dont use bolding so erratically. Just keep it simple and only use bold when it is really important. Also can you be more specific? Have you changed anything recently that could cause your site to slow down?

Comment: no Josh. i'vent touched anything

Comment: Is this on shared hosting?  If so, likely your webhost is having problems.

Comment: user1389596: Ovh is ok!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good place to start would be to check the page using some tools such as [Google Pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights#url=http_3A_2F_2Fshopfarmacia.it_2Fstore_2F&mobile=false), [Yahoo Y!Slow](http://yslow.org/) and [Pingdom Tools](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/q74eYwpQP/http://shopfarmacia.it/store/) and follow their recommendations for speeding up your site.

It doesn't seem like Zen Cart is much of a problem, every page you view requires you to download 700k of data, most of which isn't cached.

Comment: That seems much faster than what your host has.